# Rendering issue of Kendo UI JQuery - Gantt Chart on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, kendo-gantt

When i render Gantt on IE 11 or below i have issue of rendering tasks on Gantt.

It shows empty Gantt and also, in couple of IE 11 versions it renders the tasks but fails to allow editing.

Please suggest what could be the problem and how it can be resolved.

Comment: I checked [the demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/gantt/index) on the official site and it can run well in IE 11. You could use F12 dev tools to debug your code, check if there's any error in console. You should also provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you ask the question. So that we can test it on our sides and see how to help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. I will be providing the sample workable code to have better understanding on the issue. But it may take a bit time as i am working on other high priority tasks of the project.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can inform me when you have updated.